# Firebase Mobile Authentication Not working in Release Mode after updating to recent libraries

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, proguard

My Firebase based application was running fine, steadily picking up users. But today I posted a small update while updating the Firebase libraries including the authentication library to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:19.3.2'
```

It is also my first release that uses Android Studio 4.0
I had been delaying the update as there is some issue with compatibility with Proguard with the recently released version. Testing in the debug mode did not throw up any issue with the new libraries.

But since the release, the mobile authentication of the app is not working. The onVerificationFailed error that I get is provided with the following image.

[image]

Since this works in debug mode, but fails in the release mode, I suspect that this could be an issue with Proguard (not sure though). My proguard rules are as follows:

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```

But the recent version of Android Student 4.0 provides an Unresolved Class Name error with these rules. I checked in other sections of Stackoverflow and it seems this is an unsolved issue as on date.

I am scratching and banging my head for the last 12 hours with this.

Update (Adding the verification code):

```
fun verificationCallBacks(){

        mCallbacks = object: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                signIn(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {

                progressBarHolder.visibility = View.GONE
               // Toast.makeText(this@LoginPopUp, "Error: Please check the number you entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Toast.makeText(this@LoginPopUp, "Reporting Issue: $p0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

// I made this Toast to get what is happening in the release version
                if (p0 is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                } else if (p0 is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {

                }

            }

            override fun onCodeSent(p0: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                //Do something
                //Token should have been received here. But token is not sent

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Also  copy relevant error messages from logcat into the question.

Comment: have you added the sha1 key in your firebase?

Comment: The verification has been working fine for the last one month in the release version. Only after this update was made. Things are not working. Users uses the phone verfication method to login

Comment: I have added the verification call back functions. So basically now the code gets into the verification failed part of the code.